# How do I refresh my input file tag's selected file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-io, input

Currently, I have an `input type="file"` which allows me to select a file mainly to upload images as shown below

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="file-upload">
```

It looks like this in the views

[image]

I click on the choose file button and select a file
[image]

and then the input tag/button turns to.

[image]

I want to create a function that when I call it, it will refresh just the input tag/function back to "No file chosen" without `location.reloading()` the entire page. 
So back to:

[image]

I've tried to create a jQuery event that simulates a click of the input file button and then simulates a esc keypress

```
var esc = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 27 });
$( "#file-upload" ).click();
$( "#file-upload" ).trigger(esc);
```

However, due to security issues browsers do not support this ability. I also tried replacing the HTML itself by

```
document.getElementById("refreshInput").innerHTML = "<input type='file' accept='image/*' capture='camera' id='file-upload'>";
```

This also is not what I am looking for. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: $( "#file-upload" ).val("")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This question was answered in a comment long ago, so I'm copying that comment to a proper answer for the record.)

> `$( "#file-upload" ).val("")` – [dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) Aug 22 '14 at 22:32